# Wrapping Maybe in WriterT to add logging

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, option-type, writer-monad

I'm totally stuck and I feel like I can use some help now, just to stay sane. I want something as simple as adding logging capabilities to a function that returns `Maybe`, but no matter how hard I try I just can't get the types right.

This is (as I perceive it) the closest I could get:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer

q :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
q x = if x > 7
      then Just x
      else Nothing

qlog :: Integer -> WriterT [String] Maybe Integer
qlog x = do
  tell ["Querying " ++ show x]
  return $ q x
```

Which still yields me a typing error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Integer’ with ‘Integer’
Expected type: WriterT [String] Maybe Integer
  Actual type: WriterT [String] Maybe (Maybe Integer)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ q x
In the expression:
  do { tell ["Querying " ++ show x];
       return $ q x }
In an equation for ‘qlog’:
    qlog x
      = do { tell ["Querying " ++ show x];
             return $ q x }
```

How should I adjust the code to make it compile and work?

Thank you so much for your help, fellow Haskellers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to type-check, inner monads should be [**lifted**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Lifting):

```
lift :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
```

So, instead of `return $ q x`  you need to write: `lift $ q x`; as in:

```
qlog :: Integer -> WriterT [String] Maybe Integer
qlog x = do
  tell ["Querying " ++ show x]
  lift $ q x
```

Comment: This is probably the only thing I didn't try, which I should have. It does work indeed, thank you! You saved me from some more banging of my head against the wall :-)